# How to create a new product type in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, php-7

I have created new product type in magento2 using https://www.classyllama.com/blog/custom-product-types-magento-2.

After the i can't see any product info in view page.. It only display the Images tab in view page..

[image]

**product_type.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="custom_product_type_code" label="Custom Product Type Label" modelInstance="XXX\CustomiseProductInfo\Model\Product\Type" indexPriority="60" sortOrder="80" isQty="true">
    </type>
</config>
```

**Type.php**

```
class Type extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType
{
    const TYPE_ID = 'custom_product_type_code';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function deleteTypeSpecificData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        // method intentionally empty
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you see any error in `exception.log` ?

Comment: main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /var/www/html/XXX/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /var/www/html/xxx/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /var/www/html/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []

Comment: In console...ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return label }"
Message: label is not defined

Comment: @ManoM can you please update your question with product_types.xml and other files which you have created.

Comment: updated my post..

Comment: Have you not created price model?

Comment: No ..... i'm not created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below code to create custom product type.

In your **etc/product_types.xml** add following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type label="Customtype" modelInstance="XXX\CustomiseProductInfo\Model\Product\Type\Customtypecode" name="customtypecode">
        <priceModel instance="XXX\CustomiseProductInfo\Model\Product\Price"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create price model **Model/Product/Price.php** and add following code

```
<?php
namespace XXX\CustomiseProductInfo\Model\Product;

class Price extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price
{

}
```

In your **Model/Product/Type/Customtypecode.php** add following code

```
<?php
namespace XXX\CustomiseProductInfo\Model\Product\Type;

class Customtypecode extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Simple
{

    const TYPE_ID = 'customtypecode';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function deleteTypeSpecificData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        // method intentionally empty
    }
}
```

Add following code in **Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php    
namespace XXX\CustomiseProductInfo\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // associate these attributes with new product type
        $fieldList = [
            'price',
            'special_price',
            'special_from_date',
            'special_to_date',
            'minimal_price',
            'cost',
            'tier_price',
            'weight',
        ];

        // make these attributes applicable to new product type
        foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
            $applyTo = explode(
                ',',
                $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to')
            );
            if (!in_array(\XXX\CustomiseProductInfo\Model\Product\Type\Customtypecode::TYPE_ID, $applyTo)) {
                $applyTo[] = \XXX\CustomiseProductInfo\Model\Product\Type\Customtypecode::TYPE_ID;
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    $field,
                    'apply_to',
                    implode(',', $applyTo)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please try and let me know if any issue.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: are you getting any error ? in exception log or system log ?

Comment: After clearing cache its working fine.....thanks.

Comment: Its neccessary to add installdata and price model for new product?

Comment: Installdata is necessary but price model is not

Comment: Why we need to extend Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Simple instead of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType

Comment: because new product type depends on type of product you want to create like for simple, configurable, Virtual, etc.. , so there are different class for different product type, that's why we should use any of the product type class need to extand.

Comment: And one more doubt ....can you please explain ... By default, the newly created product having the special price attributes like cost, special_from_date...then why we need to add install data for this custom type?

Comment: When this installscript is run, these product attributes will show in the admin when editing or creating a product of the new type

Comment: 'Quantity' not save when i will create new type product.

Comment: To save Qty add 'isQty="true"' in 'type' node: <type label="Customtype" modelInstance="XXX\CustomiseProductInfo\Model\Product\Type\Customtypecode" name="customtypecode" isQty="true">